# Linux Script to check for file name

Tags: bash, shell

In our inbound directory we have the following file structure.

```
abc.csv.timestamp 
abc.csv.timestamp
abc.csv.timestamp
```

I want to find the most recent file in the directory and MOVE to another directory.
However i want to pass the file pattern abc.csv.* as a string to the command.

Any pointers ?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please post what you tried already.

Comment: What format are the timestamps in? Do they sort lexicographically the same as the time? If so, you can use `ls $pattern | sort | tail -1`

Comment: See [ask] then [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output plus what you have tried so far.